# How do you transfer files between Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, transfer

I was able to transfer photos from my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 to my Toshiba notebook using bluetooth, once.

Now nothing I do seems to allow me to repeat the miracle.  Anyone know what settings on both the Windows machine and the tablet are needed?

Comment: Bluetooth only? Not a cable?

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the cable and Kies, I had success using [Medieval's Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/)

you need to have wifi connection between your android and to your computer, either laptop or desktop as long as in the same network. Install this app then activate AirDroid to your tab then input the IP Address to your web browser then password if provided then you can now browse the directory inside your tab. Take note that on the storage media are available android system directory is not included even you have root access.